# Problem with inserting values after creating a TRIGGER

Tags: mysql

I am new in `mysql` and I am facing a problem I can't overcome, so I need your help.

I have created a trigger that looks like this:

```
delimiter //

CREATE trigger NEWBOOKTRIGGER138
after insert ON NEW_SALES

FOR each row

BEGIN

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NEW_SALES NS
        INNER JOIN NEW_BOOKS NB ON NS.ISBN=NB.ISBN GROUP BY GENRE)>138 then
        update GENRE set genre=GENRE|| "BEST.SELLER";
    ELSEif (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NEW_SALES NS   
        INNER JOIN NEW_BOOKS NB ON NS.ISBN=NB.ISBN GROUP BY GENRE)<=138 then
        update GENRE set genre= GENRE;
    end if;
END;//
```

In order to change the `genre title`(in table `new_books`) into `genre BEST.SELLER` if a book appears more than 138 times in the `new_sales` table, let's say.
I get a message that the trigger was successfully created.

The problem is that when I try to insert a tuple in `new_books` table (in order to see if the trigger actually works) I get an `Error code 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row.`

I try to insert the tuple this way:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_SALES(ISBN,cid) 
VALUES ("6666666666666",555);
```

When I drop the trigger the above insert command works just fine,
But how can I test the functionality of the trigger if I can't insert a new tuple?

Thank u in advance guys.
Kostas

Comment: *"But how can i test the functionality of the trigger??"*  There is the million dollar question right there.. Stored program debugging in MySQL is pretty much impossible..    Because when a trigger is created it can still give errors which you found out yourself already..

Comment: Triggers (and stored procedures to a lesser extent) can be hard to debug; a good first step is to go through and check what the queries you are using do when run outside of the trigger. (Hint: a lot of them should not work, since NEW and OLD are only available within a trigger, and should be used for the majority of trigger queries).

Comment: Initial observations: (1) an explicit `GROUP BY` kind of implies multiple results, (2) your update queries would attempt update the entire GENRE table (it has no WHERE clause)...with the GENRE table?

Comment: With other words to add to @Uueerdo 's comment. The topicstarter should see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) to provide example data, expected results and or a user case.. And or provide all table structures involved in the question -> `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be updating the wrong table, I assume you want to update the `genre` column in the `NEW_BOOKS` table. And it only seems necessary to update it for the book that you're currently inserting, which is `NEW.isbn`, so you don't need a `JOIN`.

Also, MySQL doesn't use `||` for concatenation, it uses the function `CONCAT()`.

```
CREATE trigger NEWBOOKTRIGGER138
after insert ON NEW_SALES

FOR each row
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NEW_SALES WHERE isbn = NEW.isbn) > 138
    THEN 
        UPDATE NEW_BOOKS AS b
        SET genre = CONCAT(genre, "BEST.SELLER")
        WHERE b.isbn = NEW.isbn;
```

You don't need an `ELSEIF` statement, since you don't need to do anything to keep the genre the same.

Comment: FWIW, you can set `sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT` to get ANSI SQL string concatenation syntax.

Comment: Yes, I know it's possible to make MySQL look like an ANSI SQL language. But when I see people using it, I naturally assume it's due to ignorance of MySQL's quirks, not intentional.